# Как перехватить ошибку соединения с сервером retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Хочу написать приложение под андроид для работы с апи. Пример реализация взял [с ютюба](https://youtu.be/sBCE_hOFnQU).
Если сервер запущен то пример работает, но если сервер остановлен получаю ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ua.com.m4soft.spda, PID: 12602
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.200.110 (port 8801) from /10.0.2.16 (port 56462) after 10000ms
```

Подскажите в каком месте ее нужно перехватывать.
Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Сначала покажите как вы запрос отправляете. Вообще в логах падения должна быть в т.ч. строка на которой собственно программа падает. Сам перехват ошибки можно сделать по разному в разных местах. Какой способ и где использовать - зависит от задачи. В вашем случае, скорее всего, там же надо перехватывать try/catch-ем где вы и отправляете запрос или там где его результат пытаетесь получить, что так же зависит от того, как вы запрос отправляете. В общем - без кода можно очень долго писать много лишнего. Просто покажите код.